# Haskell - Saving string input into a list

Tags: list, loops, haskell, input, io

I'm a Haskell beginner and I am doing a small file for a project that should take the input of interaction data for groups of two people and save it to a list to be output at the end. I have done my best to implement this but it seems like the program hits the "stop" case no matter what is input. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

```
import Data.List
import Text.Read

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "This program is a means to record interactions between individuals during the COVID-19 pandemic."
    putStrLn "Please enter your interactions in this format: 'x interacted with y'"
    inputs <- getUserInputs
    putStr "input: "
    putStrLn ("list sequence " ++ show (inputs))

parseInput :: String -> Maybe String
parseInput input = if input == "stop" then Nothing else (readMaybe input):: Maybe String

getUserInputs :: IO [String]
getUserInputs = do 
    input <- getLine
    case parseInput input of
    Nothing -> return []
    Just aString -> do
        moreinputs <- getUserInputs
        return (aString : moreinputs)
```

Comment: readMaybe only succeeds for quoted strings, so if you enter `"a"` it will work, but not `a`. You probably want to drop the readMaybe and have simply `... else Just input`.

Answer (score 1):

`Show` and `Read` are intended to produce and consume the representation of a value as a Haskell expression. That’s why when you call `show` on a `String`, it produces a *quoted* string:

```
> show "beans"
"\"beans\""
```

Therefore `Read` expects the string to be quoted as well, so `readMaybe` is always returning `Nothing` in your code because you’re not supplying quotes:

```
> readMaybe "beans" :: Maybe String
Nothing

> readMaybe "\"beans\"" :: Maybe String
Just "beans"
```

Therefore the fix is simple: remove the call to `readMaybe` and just return the string directly:

```
parseInput1 :: String -> Maybe String
parseInput1 input = if input == "stop"
  then Nothing
  else Just input
```

Which, as a matter of style preference, you could also write with guards, pattern matching, or the `Maybe` monad instead of `if`:

```
parseInput2 input
  | input == "stop" = Nothing
  | otherwise = Just input
```

```
parseInput3 "stop" = Nothing
parseInput3 input = Just input
```

```
import Control.Monad (guard)

parseInput4 input = do
  -- ‘guard’ returns ‘Nothing’,
  -- short-circuiting the ‘do’ block,
  -- if its condition is ‘False’.
  guard (input /= "stop")
  pure input
```

`Read` and `Show` are fine for simple programs, particularly when you’re learning Haskell, but in larger applications it’s helpful to use them mostly for debug input and output and `read`ing input you’ve already validated. Parsing and pretty-printing libraries are preferable for more involved parsing and producing human-readable output, respectively; [`megaparsec`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec) and [`prettyprinter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/prettyprinter) are good default choices in that area.